# Посчитать частоту встречаемости символов в строке , отсортировать по убыванию частоты

Tags: c, массивы

Дана задача:  Написать программу, которая печатает таблицу встречаемости 
 символов для введённой строки, отсортированную по убыванию частоты.Я написал программу которая считает частоту встречаемости символа в строке , подскажите пожалуйста как их отсортировать по убыванию частоты? Вот мой код:

```
#define mflag '0'

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
```

{

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char s[255] = { 0 };
int num = 0;
printf("Введите строку: ");
gets(s);
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
{
    for (int j = i; j < strlen(s); j++) 
        if (s[i] == s[j])
            num++;
    for (int k = i + 1; k < strlen(s); k++) 
        if (s[k] == s[i])
            s[k] = mflag;
    if (s[i] != mflag)
        printf("Символ %c встречается %d раз\n", s[i], num);
    num = 0;
}

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы написали, выглядит очень странно...Никакой связи с поставленной задачей я не уловил. Вот работающий код:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


// Строка таблицы частоты встречаемости символов
struct counter_pair {
    int symbol_code;    // Код символа
    int symbol_count;   // Сколько раз этот символ встретился
};

// Функция, которая сравнивает две строки таблицы
int compar(const void *a, const void *b) {
    struct counter_pair *p1 = (struct counter_pair *)a;
    struct counter_pair *p2 = (struct counter_pair *)b;

    if (p1->symbol_count < p2->symbol_count) 
        return -1;
    else if (p1->symbol_count > p2->symbol_count)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0; 
}

// Главная функция программы
int main () {

    struct counter_pair cp[256];    // Таблица подсчёта символов
    char str[1024];         // Обрабатываемая строка
    char *rc;           // Указатель, который вернёт fgets
    int j, len;

    // Настраиваем таблицу подсчёта
    for (j=0; j<256; j++) {
        cp[j].symbol_code = j;  // Это счётчик символа с кодом "j"
        cp[j].symbol_count = 0; // Символ пока не встретился ни разу
    }

    // Обрабатываем введённую строку
    printf("Введи строку для обработки: ");
    rc = fgets(str, 1023, stdin);
    if (rc != str) {
        printf("Error !!!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // Счмтаем вхождения символов
    len = strlen(str);
    for (j=0; j<len; j++) cp[ str[j] ].symbol_count +=1;

    // Сортируем таблицу
    qsort((void *)(&cp), 256, sizeof(struct counter_pair),compar);

    // Печатаем результат
    printf("Таблица частоты встречаемости символов\n");
    for (j=0; j<256; j++) {
        if(cp[j].symbol_count == 0) continue;   // Дальше пошли нули
        printf("Символ %c встретился %d раз\n",cp[j].symbol_code, cp[j].symbol_count);
    }

}
```